# Problems with ASP.NET Authentication ticket expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application with the following web.config settings.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="525600" path="/" /> 
</authentication>
```

My problem is on the deployed application, I get logged out automatically after 5 minutes or after closing the browser. If I check the .ASPXAUTH cookie on the browser after I am logged out, it correctly shows the expiration date.

The cookie is supposed to expire after one year and it works fine on my local machine. My guess is that the ticket is getting reset, but I do not know why.

The app is ASP.NET MVC 3, .NET Framework 4.

Any insight into this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have an automatically generated machine key (formsauthentication uses that to encrypt the cookie) the app might be resetting it on the server and then it can't decrypt the one on the client.

Comment: Actually it was the host recycling the application pool because the app was consuming more resources than allowed. Thanks for the insight, gave me an idea on where to start.

Comment: @nick did u find a solution? i m having the same problem

Comment: @Muhammad yes. I wrote a workaround to automatically read the cookie and renew the ticket after the the app is reset. Its a hack but it solves the problem. Works fine now

Answer (score 1):

Are you issuing a custome token?. If so, it will override the web.config setting. Check this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/07/15/Forms-Authentication-Timeout.aspx) for details.

Comment: I am not issuing a customer token or overriding the default settings in any way

Comment: Is this a sessiontimeout? try this http://forums.asp.net/t/1283350.aspx/1?How+to+increase+session+timeout+to+8+to+9hrs+

Comment: how does the session expiration affect forms authentication ticket?